# How to use OkHttpClient on below Apache HttpClient code

Tags: android, okhttp

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
         HttpPut put = new HttpPut("url");
         put.addHeader("X-Apikey","");
         StringEntity se = new StringEntity( version.toString());  
         se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
         put.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
         put.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
         put.setEntity(se);


         try{

               HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(put, localContext);
               HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Here, I need a help to replace HttpClient with OkHttpClient with its all subsequent parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The [okhttp-apache](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-apache) module let's you do this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new OkApacheClient();
```

It doesn't do everything Apache HTTP client can do, but it does make it easier to migrate.

Comment: Yes, It can create new HTTP client but, unable to execute in PUT,POST,GET merhod. It shows that ".excute(put) is not valid. Can  you please help me to implemengt this withoud URLconnection?

Comment: Thanks for fixing my typo, jw!

Comment: would you please explain it in detail?

Comment: From Readme of OkApacheClient(https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-apache) "Warning: Many core features of Apache HTTP client are not implemented by this API. This includes the keep-alive strategy, cookie store, credentials provider, route planner and others."